# LWC updateRecord returns 403 forbidden when using Guest User

Tags: lightning-web-components, user-management

I am trying to use the updateRecord() lightning/uiRecordApi function to update fields on a record in the system as a Guest User. From consoling out the res, I am getting an error of "An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again." with status code 403.

Will I have to create my own updateRecord() controller with "without sharing" to get around this 403 forbidden? I am assuming that the standard updateRecord() from Salesforce has sharing settings enforced so no Guest User can update records.

Comment: That's not sharing access, that's object and field level access - and the guest user has at most read-only access.

Comment: It's kind of a pain, esp when doing things like getting access to records that will help the Guest User become a paid user. I generally use a platform event driven strategy to get around this. (fire and handle the event to escape context)

Comment: Here: I've detailed it in this answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/337660/550

Comment: Yeah I double checked objects/field level access for this Guest User profile and it has Read/Create on the object and read/edit access on all of the applicable fields on the object.

Comment: The Guest User profile cannot have create on any object. Is this some sort of custom guest user profile?

Comment: Yes its a custom guest user profile